# Long observeChanges call during login

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts, kadira

We are seeing very slow login response times on our Meteor app. As load approaches 200 logins/minute the observeChanges calls become quite slow:[image: Login method]

[image: ObserveChanges large]

As loginWith<service> is part of Meteor core, this problem seems difficult to debug. Note that we only see these slow response times once the app hits 100-200 logins/min <strike>second</strike>. When there is less load on the app the observeChanges only take a few ms. Any idea what could be causing this?

EDIT: Added a stack trace with the slow items expanded:
[image: ObserveChanges large]

Comment: I have always thought that the reactive loginServiceConfiguration was overkill for a large production app. However, I'm not sure how to avoid using it

Comment: 200 logins/sec? Wow.

Comment: Can you expand each of those and post the details under "SHOW MORE"? As well, what does your observer re-use look like for this?

Comment: oplog will solve this issue, see [this blog post](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-mongodb-replica-set-for-oplog-tailing)

Comment: @dr.dimitr Thanks for your comment but we are using the oplog. Kadira shows that the oplog is enabled with the green "Using Oplog" tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, it looks like you've defined a custom publication for returning individual user details. As a troubleshooting step, if you're not interested in this query being reactive, try disabling reactivity:

```
Meteor.publish('currentUser', function () {
  return Users.find({
    _id: this.userId
  }, {
    fields: {
      emails: 1,
      registered_emails: 1,
      services: 1,
      isPremium: 1,
    },
    reactive: false,
  });
});
```

To take things further (if you want to keep things reactive), you might want to look into leveraging [Meteor 1.3's poll/diff tweaking capabilities](http://info.meteor.com/blog/tuning-meteor-mongo-livedata-for-scalability), to see if that makes a difference. So instead of relying on the oplog for your user publication, try disabling it for that specific query, and tweak the `pollingIntervalMs` and `pollingThrottleMs` options. So something like:

```
Meteor.publish('currentUser', function () {
  return Users.find({
    _id: this.userId
  }, {
    fields: {
      emails: 1,
      registered_emails: 1,
      services: 1,
      isPremium: 1,
    }
  }, {
    disableOplog: true,
    pollingThrottleMs: 10000, 
    pollingIntervalMs: 10000,
  });
});
```